# Integral with parameter $t$: $\int_{0}^{1}\displaystyle \ln\left(x^2 + t^2\right)dx$

Tags: integration

I've got the next integral with parameter $t$: $$\int_{0}^{1}\ln\left(x^2 + t^2\right) dx.$$

My question is, how to solve it ...

Comment: take t as a constant and integrate the same way you would do with  a function without parameters

Comment: From integral table:  $\int ln(x^2+t^2)dx=xln(x^2+t^2)-2x+2tarctan\frac{x}{t}$.  Put in the endpoints to get what you want.

Comment: Use Feynman's technique

Comment: What is Feynman's technique, @Digamma?

Comment: Feynman's technique is nothing but differentiation under the integral sign wrt $t$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\int_{0}^{1} \ln\left(x^2+t^2\right)dx=\ln(1+t^2)-2+2t\left(\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{t}\right)\right)$$.

From Gradshteyn and Ryzhik.  Note that the table has the indefinite integral.  I just simply applied end points here.  See comment above.

Answer (score 1):

$$I=\int_0^1\log(x^2+t^2)dx$$
Integration by parts:
$$dv=dx\qquad u=\log(x^2+t^2)\\v=x\qquad du=\frac{2x}{x^2+t^2}dx$$
Thus, $$I=uv\bigg|_0^1-\int_0^1vdu$$
$$I=x\log(x^2+t^2)\bigg|_0^1-\int_0^1\frac{2x^2}{x^2+t^2}dx$$
$$I=\log(1+t^2)-2\int_0^1\frac{x^2}{x^2+t^2}dx$$
Substitution:
$$x=t\tan\theta\\dx=t\sec^2\theta\ d\theta$$
$$\int\frac{x^2}{x^2+t^2}dx=t^2\int\frac{\tan^2\theta}{t^2\tan^2\theta+t^2}\sec^2\theta\ d\theta$$
$$=\int\frac{\tan^2\theta}{\tan^2\theta+1}\sec^2\theta\ d\theta$$
$$=\int\tan^2\theta\ d\theta$$
$$=\int\sec^2\theta\ d\theta-\int d\theta$$
$$=\tan\theta\ -\theta$$
$$=\frac{x}t-\arctan\bigg(\frac{x}t\bigg)$$
Plugging in:
$$I=\log(1+t^2)-2\bigg(\frac{x}t-\arctan\bigg(\frac{x}t\bigg)\bigg)\bigg|_0^1$$
$$I=\log(1+t^2)+2\arctan\bigg(\frac1t\bigg)-2$$

Comment: Thank you for the nice explanation! ;)

Comment: @user124942 you are very welcome. :)